# indexOf a jQuery object always returns -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexof

I am using jQuery and want to store a list of hovered elements in an array. The code I am using is below (you can paste it into an empty html document to test it):

```
<div class="element" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var hovered = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".element").hover(function(){
        hovered.push($(this));
        console.log(hovered.indexOf($(this)));
    });
});
</script>
```

Whenever I hover over the div, -1 always gets logged to the console. Why is this and what is a potential workaround?

Comment: Because `{} === {} // false` two objects are never equal to one another.

Comment: You are constructing two different objects. the one you push and the one you look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
hovered.push(this)
```

and

```
hovered.indexOf(this)
```

Comment: How is that a good solution? He should just use 'this' OR keep a reference to the created jQuery object, push it, and use it in the lookup.

Comment: yeah sure he can use just the this and keep the dom element

Answer (score -1):

You are creating two distinct jQuery objects, The one you push, and the one you 
pass to indexOf(..)

Change your code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".element").hover(function() {
        var $this = $( this );

        hovered.push( $this );

        console.log( hovered.indexOf( $this ) );
    });
});
```